The total variation TV of a continuous function and its Absolute Value
Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function such that $|f|$ has bounded variation. I want to show that $f$ has bounded variation and $V(f) = V(|f|)$, where $V$ is the total variation defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation, definition 1.1.
I have had trouble with that because i didn't manage to show this inequality: $V(f) \le V(|f|)$, even with a tip.
The professor suggest me to take a partition $P: t_0 = a \le \cdots \le t_n = b$ and take $y_k \in (t_{k+1}, t_i)$ where $f$ eventually vanishes. But i didn't be able to conclude the result.
Can anyone give me one more suggestion?

For any $x \lt y$, $\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert = \lvert \lvert f(x) \rvert  - \lvert f(y) \rvert \rvert $ if $f(x),f(y)$ have the same sign. Otherwise, it exists $x \lt z \lt y$ such that $f(z)=0$ and then $\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert = \lvert \lvert f(x) \rvert  - \lvert f(z) \rvert \rvert + \lvert \lvert f(z) \rvert  - \lvert f(y) \rvert \rvert$.

But in the second case i'd get $|f(x) - f(y)| = ||f(x)| - |f(z)|| + ||f(z)| - |f(y)|| = ||f(x)| - 0| + |0 - |f(y)|| = |f(x)| + |f(y)|$, and this doesn't work in general.

This works as I wrote when the signs of $f(x)$ and $ f(y)$ differ.

I got it! You're right! Thank you so much!
